# How to pass C# class object to c++ unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, marshalling

I have an object in c# code defined as follows:

```
class CSObject
{
  int length;
  int width;
  IList<SubItem> Items;
  bool OnSale;     
  ItemType type; //ItemType is an enum
}

Class SubItem
{
    object AssociatedValue;
    List< Range > Highlight; // Range is another class represents a pair (0, 4)
    string Name;
    IList<SubItem> Items;
    string Title;

}
```

Now how do we pass this to a method in C++ code?

1. Do I need to create similar classes on C++ side and send this data and derseialize there?
2. I don't need to modify the object on C++ side, just need to walk over it.

Comment: You can find the answers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eshywdt7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -2):

I don't Know this can help you but I used some thing like this very time ago

```
  public struct AccountInfo
  {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] ExpirationDate;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 12)]
    public string CustomerId;
  }
```